# Portable player? Yes. Portable codecs? Not so fast there, buddy

Tags: windows-xp, video-codecs, portable-apps

I have come across a very rare, interesting problem. I need to play video on a computer with Windows XP on which I have no system-wide privileges. I cannot install any software. However, I can run executables, naturally, as long as they stay away from system32 and folders like that. That's why I downloaded Media Player Classic (portable), and there is no problem running it. Nevertheless, I got it to run only to find that the computer doesn't have the codecs needed to play files such as `.mp4`, `.mkv`, `.avi`. Of course it will play `.wmv` but video files nowadays don't come in that format that often, do they?

So, my problem seems to be solvable only by one of these **two alternatives** (assuming I don't change the video file itself in any way):

- A program which already carries the ability to play these formats itself (it would mean the executable carries the codecs)
- Some sort of portable codecs. Codecs that can be read by the player without having to be actually installed for everyone to use.

I don't know which one of these alternatives is the most likely, but I certainly expect at least one of them to be possible, so as to find the solution to this conundrum.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [VideoLAN (Client)](http://www.videolan.org/). While the official release is an installer, you can extract it with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (available as a portable version), or just get a [portable](http://www.google.com/search?q=vlc%20portable) version of VLC. VLC supports most video formats via `DLL` files in its own folder, so it does not need to rely on codecs installed on the system (though you *can* configure it to use those instead).

Comment: Best VLC Portable: http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable

Answer (score 8):

[Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) also exist as portable and have internal support for a [big list of codecs](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/media-player-features.html)

Comment: Doesn't the OP already have MPC, its just the codecs are a problem?

Comment: @TheLQ - Two separate projects

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) (basically a front-end on top of [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)), which also has a portable version you can download.