# VLC not playing .mkv file containing Dirac video

Tags: matroska, video-codecs, portable-apps

I am using the VideoLAN player (portable) on a Windows XP computer on which I have regular user privileges. I can't install software of any sort, so the answer to my problem can't be about changing software or installing anything. The reasons for which I'm using VLC can be found [in this other question](https://superuser.com/q/388912/117312). It's doing great playing most video files, but I can't get it to play an `.mkv` file which serves as a container for a film encoded with [Dirac](http://diracvideo.org/). The [wiki at VideoLAN](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_Features_Formats#Widely_Used_Video_Codecs) tells me I shouldn't be having these problems, as VideoLAN comes with a Dirac decoder and a Matroska demuxer. In spite of this, I'm having problems playing this format, although the audio sounds just perfect. I'm thinking perhaps there's a way of obtaining the `.dll` codec file for Dirac that works with VLC so it could be added to VLC's folder, since it reads codecs from its own folder not from the system. Remember, **I do not have root privileges on this computer**.

Comment: I added a response to your other question, mentioning [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/). You might give that a try instead.

Comment: Were you ever able to get VLC to play this? I have some dirac videos encoded with ffmpeg. Windows Media Player + K-Lite Codecs actually play them fine, but VLC just renders a blank screen (both Matroska and AVI). I'm trying to determine if it's a VLC problem vs. a problem with the movies (because ffmpeg is crashing on me, too).